# Custom prioritising the Parts in MEF

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, mef

Hi I am using MEF and this is my case :

```
 [ImportMany]
 public IEnumerable<Lazy<IMyInterface>> correspondingParts { get; set; }
```

Now in correspondingParts, I get all the DLL's that is exported of type IMyInterface. But, the problem is like when I use

```
foreach(var parts in correspondingParts)
{
       // do something!
}
```

Now the correspondingParts contains DLL's which are sorted alphabetically by names. I need to be able to prioritise the DLL's.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this helped! The exporter needs to be able to create an ExportMetaData which can be used to get the priority later on. [ExportMetaData("Priority", 1)].

More info @
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2010/04/01/overriding-mef-metadata.aspx